# custom export in Prestashop without using module?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to export my catalogue of products. I only need the id, name and quantity in my csv exported file but I don't know how I can customize the list of exported fields.

It will be highly appreciated if someone knows how can I do so without using a module. I tried by looking in preferences but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PrestaShop back-office -> `Advanced Parameters` -> `SQL Manager` click `Add new SQL request` and paste the following query to the `Request` field:

```
SELECT p.id_product, l.name, p.quantity FROM  ps_product AS p LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang AS l ON p.id_product = l.id_product;
```

Then fill in `Name`, click `Save` and click `Export` to export the products.